# Sort Guava Multimap by number of values

Tags: java, guava

If I have a Guava Multimap, how would I sort the entries based on the number of values for the given key?

For instance:

```
Multimap<String, String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multiMap.put("foo", "1");
multiMap.put("bar", "2");
multiMap.put("bar", "3");
multiMap.put("bar", "99");
```

Given this, when iterating over multiMap, how would I get the "bar" entries to come first (since "bar" has 3 values vs. only 1 for "foo")?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Extract the entries in a list, then sort the list :

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>(map.entries());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, String> e1, Map.Entry<String, String> e2) {
        return Ints.compare(map.get(e2.getKey()).size(), map.get(e1.getKey()).size());
    }
});
```

Then iterate over the entries.

Edit :

If what you want is in fact iterate over the entries of the inner map (`Entry<String, Collection<String>>`), then do the following :

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>> entries = 
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>>(map.asMap().entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> e1, 
                       Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> e2) {
        return Ints.compare(e2.getValue().size(), e1.getValue().size());
    }
});

// and now iterate
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : entries) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey());
    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("    Value = " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That will sort the entries individually, but now I no longer have a Multimap, just a list of Map.Entry objects.  So I have lost the grouping of values to a single key.  What I want is to keep the Multimap, but just reorder the elements so that they are in descending order based on number of values.

Comment: You said you wanted to iterate over the entries. You have a list of entries. Iterate over these entries. The MultiMap is still there, untouched. A MultiMap is not ordered, and certainly not by the number of values for a given key.

Comment: Sorry my original question was not quite clear.  I want to be able to iterate over the original Multimap, but get the highest count entries first.  Also, a TreeMultimap has sorted keys (and values), so it's not necessarily accurate to say that a Multimap is not ordered.

Comment: That's what my code does : it gives you a list of entries of the multimap to iterate over, with the highest count entries first. A MultiMap can be ordered, but the order can't change each time a value is added or removed from the map. The keys can be sorted by an instrinsic, immutable property.

Comment: eneveu's answer is doing what I want: a new Multimap that is sorted in the "descending by count per key" order.  This then allows me to iterate over the Multimap using asMap().entrySet() and get each entry, print the key, and then iterate over the values with a for loop and print each one.

Comment: You should have made explicit that you didn't want to iterate through the multimap entries (Entry<String, String>), but through the entries of the map returned by asMap (Entry<String, Collection<String>>). I would have given another, much more simple answer. Do you realize how inefficient it is to extract the entries from a multimap, copy them into a sorted set, copy them a second time into a multimap, transform the multimap into a map, and finally get the entries of the map? You could just put the entries in a list, sort the list, and iterate over it. I'll edit my answer to make you see.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  What I was really hoping was there was some easy way I wasn't aware of to have a Multimap that was automatically sorted by the value count (like a TreeMultimap), so that there wouldn't need to be an explicit sorting step after all the entries are added.

Comment: @Jeff : this is impossible, because each time a value would be added to the map, all the keys would have to be reorganized, since the order of the map would not depend on the keys, but on the number of values of each key. Two keys wouldn't compare the same way throughout the life of the map. It's thus possible for an immutable map, but not for a regular one.

Comment: Excellent...thank you!  That works exactly as I was hoping, and seems quite efficient.  Thanks for your patience with this vague-requirement-giving user! :)  Your explanation of the impossibility of having a multimap work this way is very clear and I have to say "why didn't I realize that?"  Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the Multimap's [keys Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#keys%28%29) entries, sort them by descending frequency (which will be easier once the functionality described in [issue 356](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=356) is added to Guava), and build a new Multimap by iterating the sorted keys, getting values from the original Multimap:

```
/**
 * @return a {@link Multimap} whose entries are sorted by descending frequency
 */
public Multimap<String, String> sortedByDescendingFrequency(Multimap<String, String> multimap) {
    // ImmutableMultimap.Builder preserves key/value order
    ImmutableMultimap.Builder<String, String> result = ImmutableMultimap.builder();
    for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : DESCENDING_COUNT_ORDERING.sortedCopy(multimap.keys().entrySet())) {
        result.putAll(entry.getElement(), multimap.get(entry.getElement()));
    }
    return result.build();
}

/**
 * An {@link Ordering} that orders {@link Multiset.Entry Multiset entries} by ascending count.
 */
private static final Ordering<Multiset.Entry<?>> ASCENDING_COUNT_ORDERING = new Ordering<Multiset.Entry<?>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Multiset.Entry<?> left, Multiset.Entry<?> right) {
        return Ints.compare(left.getCount(), right.getCount());
    }
};

/**
 * An {@link Ordering} that orders {@link Multiset.Entry Multiset entries} by descending count.
 */
private static final Ordering<Multiset.Entry<?>> DESCENDING_COUNT_ORDERING = ASCENDING_COUNT_ORDERING.reverse();
```

---

**EDIT: THIS DOESN'T WORK IF SOME ENTRIES HAVE THE SAME FREQUENCY (see my comment)**

Another approach, using an Ordering based on the Multimaps' keys Multiset, and [ImmutableMultimap.Builder.orderKeysBy()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.Builder.html#orderKeysBy%28java.util.Comparator%29):

```
/**
 * @return a {@link Multimap} whose entries are sorted by descending frequency
 */
public Multimap<String, String> sortedByDescendingFrequency(Multimap<String, String> multimap) {
    return ImmutableMultimap.<String, String>builder()
            .orderKeysBy(descendingCountOrdering(multimap.keys()))
            .putAll(multimap)
            .build();
}

private static Ordering<String> descendingCountOrdering(final Multiset<String> multiset) {
    return new Ordering<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String left, String right) {
            return Ints.compare(multiset.count(left), multiset.count(right));
        }
    };
}
```

Second approach is shorter, but I don't like the fact that the Ordering has state (it depends on the Multimap's key Multiset to compare keys).

Comment: Thank you!  The first approach worked great, exactly what I wanted.  Something is wrong with the second approach, though (haven't debugged it to figure out what yet...but with my test data I start with an input Multimap whose asMap() has size 432, but the output Multimap's asMap() size is only 21.

Comment: That's indeed weird. I'm going to test it when I can find some time. I might have made a mistake. You sure you aren't comparing inputMultimap.size() with outputMultimap.asMap().size()?

Comment: Correct, I was comparing asMap().size() on both.

Comment: I revisited this, and I found why the second approach doesn't work. When you use ImmutableMultimap.Builder#orderKeysBy(), the builder creates a TreeMap under the hood, which uses the given comparator to sort its keys. When two keys are equal according to the comparator, only the first is added to the map. In your case, you had 432 entries, but only 21 different "frequencies" for those entries.

Comment: The second approach results in *ascending* order, to work with the described descending order you'd need to swap the left/right in the `return Ints.compare(multiset.count(left), multiset.count(right));` line.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 streams:

```
    ListMultimap<String, String> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    multiMap.put("foo", "f1");
    multiMap.put("baz", "z1");
    multiMap.put("baz", "z2");
    multiMap.put("bar", "b1");
    multiMap.put("bar", "b2");
    multiMap.put("bar", "b3");

    Multimaps.asMap(multiMap).entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue().size()))
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> "
                    + Arrays.toString(e.getValue().toArray())));
```

Output:

```
bar -> [b1, b2, b3]
baz -> [z1, z2]
foo -> [f1]
```