# How to sort Guava MultiMap by count of values for each key

Tags: java, sorting, guava, multimap

I already saw this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881629/sort-guava-multimap-by-number-of-values), but my use case is doing it at creation process.

I can create a multimap like that :

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Foo, Bar> indexMultiMap = Multimaps.index(barCollection, new Function<Bar, Foo>() {
     @Override
     public Foo apply(Bar bar) {
        //some works
        return Foo;
     }
  });
```

I know that Foo elements will be unique, and i want to sort this map by frequency of each Foo element size of Bar collection of each Foo element) in this map, descending.

1) How can i do that with one iteration ? Like doing it when indexing this collection to MultiMap

2) If not so, what is the efficient way to get it ?

My objective is at all, when i am iterating this map, i want to see first key has the bigger count of values, like

Foo -> 3 (size of bar collection corresponding to this key)

Foo -> 3

Foo -> 2

Foo -> 1

Foo -> 1

Comment: Can you give us sample input code also?

Comment: @Xaerxess input is just a Collection<Bar> ? What do you want to see more ?

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc of `Multimaps.index()`;

**"In the returned multimap, keys appear in the order they are first encountered ..."**

If the collection is sorted in a way that 'simulates' implicit sorting behaviour, multimap will be created in the order you want. eg:

```
SortedMultiset preSorted = TreeMultiset.create(fooComparator);
```

then feed `Multimaps.index()` with above preSorted collection.

Answer (score 1):

As @px5x2 said. when you call `Multimaps.index()`, keys appear in the order they are first encountered. So, sort your collection first. Using the Guava `Multimaps.index()` example here with tiny modification.

```
ImmutableSet<String> digits = ImmutableSet.of("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine");
Function<String, Integer> lengthFunction = new Function<String, Integer>(){
    public Integer apply(String input) {
        return input.length();
    }
};
ImmutableMultimap<Integer, String> sortedOnLength = Multimaps.index(
    Ordering.natural().onResultOf(lengthFunction).sortedCopy(digits), 
    lengthFunction
);
```