# Sort a TreeMultimap in descending (reversed) order

Tags: java, collections, maps, guava, multimap

The output is: Top pincodes: `{1=[456008, 456600, 456666], 2=[560089], 4=[456098, 567789]}`

I want them to be in this order: `{4=[456098,567789], 2=[560089], 1=[456008, 456600, 456666]}`

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> totalCustomersByPin = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
TreeMultimap<Integer, Integer> totalDeliveriesToPin = TreeMultimap.create();
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = totalCustomersByPin.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> pair = iterator.next();
    totalDeliveriesToPin.put(pair.getValue(), pair.getKey());
}
System.out.println("Top pincodes:" + totalDeliveriesToPin);
```

Comment: [How to sort TreeMap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18923308/5168011)

Comment: Do you always need them in this order or sometimes in reverse sometimes not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Descending order: Java Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923167/sorting-descending-order-java-map)

Comment: @guy and RHA : this is a `Multimap` from Guava, not a regular Java `Map`

Comment: @Dici What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589716/how-to-sort-guava-multimap-key-date)? or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881629/sort-guava-multimap-by-number-of-values) ?

Comment: @Dici : exactly! This is Guava multimap. Is there any other MultiMap type rather than TreeMultimap  that can do this ?

Comment: @guy Yep, those ones are ok. Answered by the guy who wrote those classes :) Even better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a key comparator when creating the `TreeMultimap`. You can use [`Ordering.natural()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural%28%29) and then call [`reverse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#reverse%28%29) to sort the key in the reverse order of their natural ordering.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMultimap<Integer, Integer> map = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural().reverse(), Ordering.natural());
    map.put(1, 456008);
    map.put(1, 456600);
    map.put(1, 456666);
    map.put(2, 560089);
    map.put(4, 456098);
    map.put(4, 567789);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

This will print: `{4=[456098, 567789], 2=[560089], 1=[456008, 456600, 456666]}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I´ve found what is actually working for me

```
  SortedSetMultimap<String, String> multiMap = TreeMultimap.create(
                Comparator.reverseOrder(), // Key sorting
                (o1, o2) -> 0              // Value sorting
        );
```